# React Js Hooks Update Array Issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

**Hi Friends,**

> I'm new to react js i'm trying to update values in Array based on the
>   user input. But it's adding new value to my array list. i'm just
>   trying update value in array based on the index. I'm Using the
>   following code. please help to resolve this issue.

**note : I'm Using Typescript for development**

```
       const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => 
          {
            var question: QuestionDTO = tempQuestions[counter];
            question.answer = event.target.value;
            setTempQuestions((tempQuestions) => [...tempQuestions, question]);
          };

       const onClickHandler = () => {
        if (tempQuestions.length !== counter + 1) {
          setCounter(counter + 1);
          console.log("hey value recevied " + JSON.stringify(tempQuestions));
        } else {
          console.log("use are completed" + tempQuestions);
          props.sumbitHandler(tempQuestions);
        }
      };

      // Html Code
       <Input name="answer" onChange={handleChange}/>
       <Button onClick={onClickHandler} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you are accessing the array element by index, you are adding a new one while updating state.

You can make use of `counter` and `Array.prototype.slice` to update:

```js
const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setTempQuestions((tempQuestions) => [
        ...tempQuestions.slice(0, counter),
        {...tempQuestions[counter], answer: value}, 
        ...tempQuestions.slice(counter + 1)
    ]);
};
```

Comment: Thanks it's works. But there is any simply method is available to do this

Comment: you could map over the array and update the specific item